# Writing a post query to save data in two models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models, one that represents users and one that represents authentication. Both of these models share two fields, `user_email` and `user_password`. I am trying to write a post to generate a new user that saves this information to both tables. All of the other fields in my user model are not required, just the `user_email` and `user_password` are required and they are the only two fields in the authentication model. I know that I have the code to create the one user within one model, how do I go about inserting this data into two instead of one?

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 15).then(hash => {
    const user = new User({
      user_email: req.body.user_email,
      user_password: hash
    });
    user.save().then(result => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'User created', 
        result: result
      }).then
    }).catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: error
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you are trying to post to two models, does this describe what you are trying to do?

I went ahead and got rid of the `save()` calls, because if you are just creating you can call `create`

```js
router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 15)
    const payload = {
      user_email: req.body.user_email,
      user_password: hash
    }
    const user = await User.create(payload)
    await Authentication.create(payload)
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'User created', 
      result: user
    })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: That is a lot easier than I was expecting.  Thank you so much alilland.

Comment: How would I do this log in route for the same user sign up?, I followed a tutorial to get this and after seeing the signup you showed me, I feel like I have been misled.

Comment: heres an old nodejs app i wrote a long time ago with a user signup, its slightly outdated and uses callbacks instead of async/await but it might help https://github.com/alilland/nodejs-api